# Help merging files using a bash loop

Tags: bash

I am new to bash and have a list of text(.txt) files I would like to merge together that look like the below:

```
1.unmapped.F.fq
1.unmapped.R.fq
1.unmapped.s.fq
2.unmapped.F.fq
2.unmapped.R.fq
2.unmapped.s.fq
```

I would like to merge the F/R/s files together to create an output that looks like the following:

```
1.unmapped.all.fq
2.unmapped.all.fq
```

I've merged simpler named files in R using something like

```
for(i in 1:10){
  data <- paste0("A.",i)
  assign(paste0("data",i), read.csv(data))
}
```

but am not sure what to do in bash as there are 2 places with changing inputs (1/2 and F/R/s), or if a loop is even the best approach.

Comment: Does the contents have to be in a specific order or just beginning with `unmapped.F` and ending with `unmapped.s`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, try this:

```
for i in {1..2}; do # 1 to 2 just to match with the sample posted
  cat "$i".unmapped.{F,R,s}.fq >> "$i".unmapped.all.fq
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. If instead of F/R/s I had numbers 1-100, the following seems to be the right way to go based on your answer:

```
for j in {1..3};
do
    
    for i in {1..2};
    do cat "$i".unmapped."$j".fq >> "$i".unmapped.all.fq
    done
done
```

Please pardon my formatting woes...